# What might cause ArcGIS Online Public Account to reset and lose all content?

Tags: arcgis-online, authentication

I have two ArcGIS Online accounts:

- ArcGIS for Organizations which I log into as a named user
- Public Account which I log into as a Gmail user

Today, I logged into my Public Account and as I did so I saw a message which said something about "resetting" before the login proceeded.

When I visited My Content I found that all of the considerable content that I authored there last week was gone.

If anybody else has experienced this can you tell me the likely/precise wording of the "resetting" message that I saw, so that I can submit this to my local Esri support to look into?

---

I now think the intermittent issue above is probably unrelated to the reset message which I have since seen again without loss of content:

> Your login session has been reset. Please try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged a support incident with our local support, and a few hours later, before receiving contact with their technical staff 24 hours later, I re-checked my Public Account and the content had re-appeared.

I found out that they had reported it to Redlands but I am not sure if anything was done to restore it.

I have since seen the issue twice more, but only for a few minutes at a time so I think there is an intermittent issue where the content just seems to have disappeared.

---

As an update Redlands and local Esri support continue to investigate this with me.